# How to use oxford5k for training?

Tags: machine-learning, datasets, training-datasets

Generally, we have training data with landmark IDs, their GTs (positive samples), and then separate query images and corresponding positive samples for evaluation.
In the Oxford5k or [ROxford5k](https://github.com/filipradenovic/revisitop), one finds the landmark images and other images for that landmark. For example, everything starting with all_souls correspond to the all_souls building. Nevertheless, when I see other images containing this tag, it contains people and indoor images, which are possibly junk (But they are not, I guess). In the GT files, I see files like all_souls_1_query.txt, all_souls_1_good.txt, all_souls_1_ok.txt, all_souls_1_junk.txt, and so on.
I want to make sure I get the standard practice of how to train on these datasets and evaluate it properly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your task? What task are you trying to solve? It seems that your problem is related to "data preprocessing", i.e. you want to know how to pre-process the data in these mentioned datasets. I recommend that you use the tag [tag:data-preprocessing].

Comment: @nbro, I am just starting to train a model on this dataset but I found structure of it to weird. but it is widely-used dataset and I just want to know how experts use this dataset.